# ValueError: could not convert string to float:'\ufeff2', how to convert different types data in a array to float type?

Tags: numpy, python-3.5

I have tried to run the code bellow, but there is a error message, does anyone know how to convert different types data in a array to float type?

My code:

```
data_in=[['1', '-1.24', '1', '458', 1, 0, 0], ['2', '-1.54', '1', '440', 0, 0, 0], ['3', '-2.04', '1', '440', 1, 0, 0] ] 
data=np.asarray(data_in, dtype=float)
```

Comment: What code below? There is no code below your question.

Comment: Please don't add it as a comment, edit your question instead please.

Comment: Your example works in my case. Which numpy version do you have?

Comment: I didn't face any issue with your code while running.please elaborate your issue

Comment: my numpy version is1.18.0. This example code works while running. Actually, the size of data_in(about 8G) is very large, when run data=np.asarray(data_in, dtype=float),  'VauleError: could not convert string to float:'\ufeff2' ' is reported. I cannot figure out the reason till now